# Is it right to use full Java EE in this approach vs just a Web and Persistence Tier?

Tags: java, web

I want to devlop a site for managing sport stats. Lets say soccer stats. I want to pusblish a front end site with nice presentation for the public, no login required.

Im building a second site for the soccer leagues back office. This sites is where the soccer leagues will register their games anotation sheet so the statitics of each player will be calculated from that game. Here the league will register the instructors, catogories (range of age), and players.

I thougth using Full Java EE architecture. Develope an EJB project common both for front end and back office webapps, and a Front End and Back Office as I mentioned. Im planning using wicket for both sites. But I'm planning to publish on a 1GB RAM VPS with Glassfish 3.

Another option is to make a common project(eclipse), and make 2 webapps using that common project. That common project is a JPA project and have some common dependencies (Apache commons lang), that I will use in all projects. So deploy to tomcat and go simple.

So I'm a litte confused and have some specific questions:

1. Should I use Static methods (I can deploy on tomcat, less RAM usage I guess), o Stateless Session Beans (Need EE appserver) for the services?
2. Should I use wicket for the Front End since Wicket is stateful and im going stateless here? where can I find some stateless wicket tutorial?

Im asking since Im not clear in when using bean is innecessary. Should I go full EE  or just use the Web and Persistence tier.

-----Update------
Im actually the only developer and I have only experience with wicket for web tier.

Im not sure about using wicket for the front end since is statefull and front end will just show info to everyone.

The separation of web tier and front end is because I have different designs/site templates, one prettier (FE) style mlb.com and another more admin(nice forms and components) based. Are two site templates I purchased.

Its a project that I want to develop and learn. Its a commercial one And I foresee extending this application supporting others sports like tennis, basketball, and so on.

Comment: I have put a -1 to the question because the title doesn't tell me anything about the question.

Comment: In my opinion the title is still misleading: it sounds like "what web profile should I use" but actually you're asking for "how should I separate frontend and backoffice/management into deployment artifacts". My understanding of your question is whether to separate these two projects or not and if it has impact to the performance (?).

Comment: Plenty questions pop up in my head: Are you the sole developer? What products are you comfortable using? Is this work or hobby? Do you wish to learn from it? What future changes and extensions to the application do you foresee?

Comment: General comment on project management: I'd suggest you to start with a single project. In my experience trying to separate a project that *seems* to be two projects from the beginning sets the complexity level to a quiet high level. In my opinion you should develop everything in one project and if *really* necessary separate things out. The only reason for separating frontend and backoffice in my opinion is security and access/realm management (this *might* be complex when managed in one project).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every developer is going to have his or her own preferences and recommendations.

From my personal development experience, EJBs have become a lot less "heavy/cumbersome" in the transition from EJB 2.1 to EJB 3.0 specification.

At this point, EJB 3.0 are just annotated POJOs.  However, I would not necessarily recommend using Stateless Session EJBs unless you believe you are going to need the features provided by EJB container (for instance container-managed transaction/rollback).

if you want a great full stack that can run on `Tomcat` without needing a Java EE Container, I would recommend [Grails](http://www.grails.org/).  It will include your Web tier (in the form of GSPs and Taglibs), and will also provide your persistence tier (GORM), and you can do very rapid development.

Now, to be absolutely honest, 1 GB RAM is a bit light for Grails.  I believe it will run, but I would want at least 2 GB RAM if I were running the Grails stack.

You may also consider [Spring Web MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) for your Web tier and Spring beans for your service layer, and plugging in JPA/Hibernate for your persistence tier.

I am personally not familiar in-depth with Wicket (I know of it, but do not have any hands-on experience with it).  However, some quick searches showed articles on integrating it with Spring.

Answer (score -1):

If it were me, I'd look at using the Spring framework. I'd create a persistence layer using JPA, 2 client apps communicating to that persistence layer using Spring MVC and whatever presentation technology you'd like (keep it simple with Velocity, Freemarker, JSP .  Deploy via Tomcat.  I see no reason to use EE -- from what you've described you've just need a servlet container, nothing else that a Java EE server brings along.